# Two different google tag manager accounts in same domain

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have two google tag manager accounts one mine and another of third party website and I need to put these 2 in this third party website.
I tried put two gtm scripts after body tag opening but I saw duplicated content of both accounts.

How can I do this? 
It's possible?

Comment: Why are you using 2 different google tag manager containers? You can just add all the codes in one container.

Comment: I'm using because one account I can't access and another is mine.

Comment: This question's answers are old and no longer relevant except one: look at the answer from Yogesh Awdhut Gadade.

Answer (score 21):

This is because both GTM tags are using the default "dataLayer".  See below:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe...
(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Give one or both custom dataLayer names like so...([documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#renaming)):

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script’,'gtm1dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

After that you should see no duplicate events firing from either container.

Comment: Voted up for the link to the documentation and clear example, however it seems that Google recommends using a common datalayer on that very page.

Comment: The specification was updated some 6 months ago. Currently, the [only standing recommendation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide?hl=en#multiple-containers) for multiple containers is to use the **same** dataLayer name for each container. That is the only way that it will work without conflicts.

Comment: When using the same `dataLayer` variable we're seeing events fire multiple times though..

Answer (score 14):

Updated information:

According to Google official document (https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide?hl=en#multiple-containers)

It suggests:

1. For the best performance of a page, keep the number of Google Tag Manager containers on the page minimal.
2. If you use more than one container on a page, implement the container snippets with a **common data layer object**.
3. Using more than one data layer can cause some triggers to stop working and could have other implications. So don't rename the data layer for a subset of containers on the page.
4. You can, if necessary, rename the data layer for all containers on the page.
5. Avoid implementing a Google Tag Manager container through a custom HTML tag in another Google Tag Manager container

For more details and example refer to this official page link: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide?hl=en#multiple-containers

Comment: This appears to be the only remaining relevant answer.

Comment: The section regarding use of multiple containers appears to have been removed from the linked article.

Answer (score 4):

There should be no issues with multiple GTM containers on the same page. Unless you have duplicate codes in the containers which are double firing pixels. You can add those containers after the opening body tag.

To check what is firing on the entire page. Download firebug for firefox and add the "omnibug" extension. The omnibug extension should be in the firefox firebug window when you open it.

When you go the omnibug in the firefox panel, you will see EVERYTHING THAT IS FIRING!

If there are duplicate tags firing in the omnibug box, then you can check the details of the event and figure out which specific tag and delete them from the GTM container that you own.

Answer (score 3):

Google tells us that you should not use two tag managers on one site.
Google Support:

```
Multiple installations of Google Tag Manager detected

We suggest you place only 1 instance of the GTM snippet on a webpage. Multiple GTM snippets don"t work well with each other
Multiple GTM snippets don"t work well with each other because of which the tag added via GTM may not always fire correctly.

Place only 1 instance of the GTM snippet on a webpage
```

https://support.google.com/tagassistant/answer/3207128?hl=en#multiple_tags

Comment: is this still valid? the link seem to work, but does not redirect to a specific section

Comment: This answer is NOT relevant to the question, and appears WRONG as of this comment. You can have multiple configs, but you need only load one script tag with the first config. The only thing you would have to do today is remove the second script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Seems possible to find any answer you like for this. According to tag manager developer guide you can add multiple containers but you should use the same datalayer.

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#multiple-containers