# Two Adobe DTM - Dynamic Tag Manager - Instances On One Site?

Tags: tags, adobe, tms

Has anyone on Stack implemented two separately controlled Adobe DTM [Dynamic Tag Manager, formerly Satellite Tag Management System] instances on a single site? My team is looking to implement our DTM instance, for delivering 3rd party marketing tags, on a partner site that already has DTM implemented. My concern is that we might run into data duplication, tag collisions or js errors.

I found a post that provides insight around running two separately controled Google Tag Manager instances on the same site [domain], but nothing around Adobe DTM: [Two different google tag manager accounts in same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465360/two-different-google-tag-manager-accounts-in-same-domain)

Any help/direction/suggestions would be appreciated.

---

Art

Answer (score 1):

DTM is not designed to have two instances on the same page. You will encounter issues with duplicate calls, namespace collisions etc..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a new "container" within the company just for the third-party marketing tags. This way, those tags can be managed independent of the existing implementation on the site. To implement the new container, simply add the container embed code to the header of the site. The _satellite call at the bottom of the page only needs to be fired once, regardless of the number of containers.